# Next.js App Router using optional URL params

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am currently working on a project that should support various types of URL parameters. In Next.js, I am using the App Router, so only “next/navigation” is functional for me, not “next/router”.

I aim to construct my URL in the following format:

/Surveys/(shortname)/id/Report

Here, both ‘shortname’ and ‘id’ are variables. However, ‘id’ is always present in the URL, while ‘shortname’ is optional. For instance:

/Surveys/helloworld/123/Report

and

/Surveys/123/Report

Both URLs should direct me to the same page, where I have:

```html
<h1>Survey shortname: helloworld</h1>
<p>ID: 123</p>
```

Or, when there is no ‘shortname’:

```html
<h1>Survey</h1>
<p>ID: 123</p>
```

My initial approach was to use the Optional Catch-all Segments provided by Next.js. However, this didn’t work out because [[…shortname]] must be the last part of the URL, and it is crucial for me to have ‘Report’ at the end.

Consequently, I considered working with slugs like [shortname] and [id] as folders. But this didn’t work out either because I couldn’t operate without ‘shortname’.

Next, I tried working with rewrite rules in my next.config.mjs. For example:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    async rewrites() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/Surveys/:shortname/:id/Reports',
                destination: '/Surveys/Reports/[...slugs]',
            },
        ];
    },
};

export default nextConfig;
```

The idea was to trick Next.js into believing that the catch-all is at the end. Unfortunately, this didn’t work out either.

I would appreciate any assistance you can provide. If u can give an example project, with an improved folder-structure and using tsx, I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello to anyone seeing this,

I fixed it with a simple [id] slug. So my folder structure was:

/Surveys/[id]/Report

Instead of just giving the id user can input also stuff like

/Survey/34234-helloworld/Report

I just take the whole slug and split it on "-".

```js
export default function Reports({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
  const idParts = params.id.split('-');
  const id = idParts[0];
  const shortname = idParts.length > 1 ? idParts[1] : null;

  return (
    <h1>
      Reports with ID: {id} 
      {shortname && ` und shortname: ${shortname}`}
    </h1>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's probably more than one way to do this, but here's an idea:

You should be able to use catchall segments, but the supported pattern requires that `[[…catchall]]` must match everything after `/Surveys/`.

You'll need to differentiate *within the page* between routes that have or don't have a `shortname` path element, have or don't have `Report`, etc.

You haven't told us in your question if `shortname` would match a pre-defined set of possible strings, or if `id` is always numeric.  These details could matter to parsing the values.

Folder structure would be:

```
// "rest" will capture all segments following `/Surveys/` into an array of variable length.
app
- Surveys
--[[...rest]]
---page.tsx
```

As described [in the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-segments), your params inside `page.tsx` would be something like:

```
For an example route: /Surveys/helloworld/123/Report

params = {rest: ['helloworld', '123', 'Report']}
```

So, you just need some logic to decide which elements of `rest`-- [0, 1, 2]--  to assign to which variables. If `shortname` is truly optional (you didn't say why you might or might not need it, but said if it's omitted, the desired page is the same?), then it sounds like all you really care about is the second-last element in the array, which is the ID.

```
const id = parseInt(rest[rest.length - 2], 10);  // get ID, convert to an integer

// If presence or absence of "Report" in the path also matters...
const isReport = rest[rest.length - 1] === "Report";
```

Then proceed with your page rendering logic.

IMO, it's probably better to structure your routes to be more specific with each added path element, and make the ID the last element, and not have optional elements that don't add any semantic meaning (shortname, I'm looking at you!)

If there are further requirements, you should update your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 'id' is always numeric, but 'shortname' can be a string or numeric too!

I will try your idea and give feedback ;)